# Jenkins Pipeline stage starts too soon

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, stage, parameterized

I'm having a problem with my pipeline. (Jenkins version 1.165.1)

I have:

- 3 clients: ('AAA', 'BBB', and 'CCC').
- 2 Parameterized Build Jobs: ('Deploy_PrepDB_SHELL' and 'Deploy_TargetDB_SHELL')

The pipeline (listed below consists of 2 Stages, one for each Parameterized Build.
Each parameterized build runs 3 times, once for each client.
Within each stage, the 3 clients can run in parallel.

**However, I want Stage #2 to run ONLY AFTER all 3 builds from the Stage #1 are complete and have successfully finished.**
My problem is that Stage #2 begins as soon as all of the builds from Stage #1 have been started.

**Stage #2 does not consider the final status of these builds...**
And so, Stage #2 begins while the builds from Stage #1 are in progress, and it's causing errors.

FWIW, using builds with hard-coded client values actually solves this problem. But I need to use parameterized builds.
We have more than 3 clients and 2 build jobs. Hard-coded builds leads to an expolosion in the number of builds.

**How can I have Stage #2 (in the pipeline) be aware of the results of Stage #1's builds? And only proceed once Stage #1's builds have succeeded?**

The solution I'm thinking of consists of using pre-actions and post-actions in the parameterized builds to read/write statuses to a DB table.
But that feels clunky, and I think Jenkins probably has some kind of simpler mechanism to handle this scenario.

Have any of you been able to implement something like this?

Thanks

```
/* Jenkins Pipeline in Groovy */

def clientlist = ['AAA', 'BBB', 'CCC']


/*
    Stage #1
*/

stage concurrency: 3, name: '1. Deploying Prep Database'
    echo 'Deploying Prep Database DacPac'

    for(item in clientlist)         
    {             
        build job: 'Deploy_PrepDB_SHELL', parameters: [[$class: 'StringParameterValue', name: 'CLIENT_NAME', value: item]], wait: false       
        Thread.sleep(1000)           
    }


/*
    Stage #2
    Should not start until all 3 builds from previous stage have successfully finished!
*/

stage concurrency: 3, name: '2. Deploying Target Database'
    echo 'Deploying Target Database DacPac'            

    for(item in clientlist)      
    {         
        build job: 'Deploy_TargetDB_SHELL', parameters: [[$class: 'StringParameterValue', name: 'CLIENT_NAME', value: item]], wait: false       
        Thread.sleep(1000)      
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried setting the `wait` parameter to true so you wait for jobs output before passing to next stage ? Not sure it will work with concurrency though...

Comment: I never set it to true, but I have removed it. And you're right, it doesn't really work with the concurrency. IIRC, each iteration within the for loop waited until the previous one completed.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that your syntax is correct for your Pipeline example - it looks like you're missing the curly braces after each `stage`.  Also, the current syntax for `stage` doesn't have a `concurrency` option (that I'm aware of.

Instead of `concurrency`, What you want here  is a `parallel` step and use the `wait: true` (default) on your `build` calls.

```
/* Jenkins Pipeline in Groovy */

def clientlist = ['AAA', 'BBB', 'CCC']

def deployPrep = [:]
def deployTarget = [:]

// Create a map of name-closure pairs
for(item in clientlist)         
{
    // Closures will be executed later by "parallel" step later in pipeline
    deployPrep[item] = {
        // "wait: true" is the default           
        build job: 'Deploy_PrepDB_SHELL',
            parameters: [[$class: 'StringParameterValue', name: 'CLIENT_NAME', value: item]]      
        // Probably don't need this sleep, but including for parity
        Thread.sleep(1000)
    }

    // We can build up multiple maps using one loop.
    // Closures will be executed later by "parallel" step later in pipeline
    deployTarget[item] = {
        build job: 'Deploy_TargetDB_SHELL', 
            parameters: [[$class: 'StringParameterValue', name: 'CLIENT_NAME', value: item]]      
        Thread.sleep(1000)
    }
}

/*
    Stage #1
*/

stage ('1. Deploying Prep Database') {
    echo 'Deploying Prep Database DacPac'
    parallel deployPrep
}

/*
    Stage #2
    Will not start until all 3 builds from previous stage have successfully finished!
*/

stage ('2. Deploying Target Database') {
    echo 'Deploying Target Database DacPac'
    parallel deployTarget
}
```

Comment: The jobs are currently hard-coded, and we are using the parallel syntax. When I first created this "shell" pipeline, I tried using the parallel syntax, but couldn't get it to work... I don't think we use curly braces in any of our stages. And the concurrency setting does seem to allow us to process in parallel. Keep in mind, we're using Jenkins 1.165.1 (It seems like Jenkins 2.x might have a slightly different pipeline setup).... I am gonna try your solution though, and let you know what happens. Thank you so much!